# Unzip file while reading it on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, zip, unzip

I am looking for a way to unzip a file while reading it.

Reason I need to do this is I need to unzip large files (over 1 gig) and other `unzip` libraries just load the whole file into memory which causes a crash.

Is there a way to do this while reading the .zip file?

Comment: The solution we had to use, which is unfortunately proprietary (but not that hard to replicate; we used zlib) was to memory-map the file in chunks, unzip those chunks on the fly, write the unzipped data back to disk, delete the original zipped file, then re-open and read the unzipped file.  This has been working well for several years now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ZipArchive](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive) provides this feature and worked for us to keep the memory footprint very low.